# Java StyledText control with IDocument support

Tags: eclipse, rcp, e4, styledtext

My intention is to code a NASTRAN text editor (plain text editor, eclipse pure E4 RCP application).
NASTRAN is an engineering structural analysis application.
Simplifying, NASTRAN uses text cards of 8-characters-width per field and up to 10 fields per card (line).
See figure with the work done so far

[image: NASTRAN EDITOR screen capture]

The main feature of this Editor is to show plain text (fixed pitch font) with colored columns background, so it can be easy to distinguish different fields in each row.

I have used a `StyledText` control which provides methods to change background:

```
styledText.setBackgroundImage(backgroundImage);
```

How can I use IDocument interface with `StyledText` so It can provide me support for:
text manipulation
positions
partitions
line information
etc...

Other text controls (TextViewer, SourceViewer) provide setDocument(IDocument) method to load and manipulate text data

```
--org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer

  |
--org.eclipse.jface.text.source.SourceViewer
```

But `StyledText` extends SWT Canvas and does not provide methods to set the imput documents

```
   --org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText
```

Alternative approach could be how can I change background in a SourceViewer control so I can have columns of different colors.

Thanks in advance

Comment: TextViewer and SourceViewer are wrappers for StyledText and provide the code to deal with the IDocument interface so you should use one of those.

Comment: TextViewer/SourceViewer does not provied method to set/filll the background with an image (in this case with columns of different colors). I have not seen any method like setBackgroundImage(Image);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks greg-449 for your answer, problem solved.
I had not a clear understanding of the concept of a class wrapping another class. So I tried first to create a StyledText object.
Now it is clear

I have attached below how I proceeded: creating a SourceViewer control and then, obtaining the StyledText wrapped.
So I could set the background image for the control

```
public class NastranEditor {
    public StyledText st = null;
    public SourceViewer sv = null;
    private Image backgroundImage;//The image to appear at the backgroud
    //....
    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct(Composite parent){
        IVerticalRuler  ruler = new VerticalRuler(20);
        sv = new SourceViewer(parent, ruler, SWT.MULTI | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        st = sv.getTextWidget();
        st.setBackgroundImage(backgroundImage);
        //....
    }
    //....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TextViewer and SourceViewer are wrappers for StyledText and provide the code to deal with the IDocument interface so you should use one of those.

You can call the `getTextWidget()` method of the viewer to get access to the `StyledText` control they are using.